# Name resolution problem in multi package go module

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a module that contains multiple packages but I don't understand why I'm getting errors.

Layout:

```
λ ~/code/go-test/src/mod-test/ » tree
.
├── cmd
│   └── a.go
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── pkg
    └── foo
        └── b.go

3 directories, 4 files
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/go-test/mod-test/cmd"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("main")
        A()
}
```

cmd/a.go:

```
package cmd

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo"
)

func A() {
        fmt.Println("a")
        B()
}
```

pkg/foo/b.go:

```
package foo

import "fmt"

func B() {
        fmt.Println("B")
}
```

go.mod:

```
module github.com/go-test/mod-test

go 1.12
```

I get the following error:

```
λ ~/code/go-test/src/mod-test/ » go build
# github.com/go-test/mod-test/cmd
cmd/a.go:5:2: imported and not used: "github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo"
cmd/a.go:10:2: undefined: B
```

Can anyone help explain what I've done wrong and why I get the error?

Thanks,

Comment: Names must be qualified. Unrelated to modules.

Comment: why am I getting multiple downvotes with no explanation?  I thought I'd been pretty clear in the question I asked and gave a minimal test case explaining what I was asking.  This feels very mean spirited!  I will gladly make edits to make the question more valuable to future users searching if people have suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Volker.  I did not know that until I had the answer.  I've removed the tag and updated the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in the `cmd/a.go`. You did not use `"github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo"`. Also `B()` is under `github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo` package, so you have to specify it. See below:

package cmd

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo"
)

func A() {
        fmt.Println("a")
        // B()
        foo.B()
}
```

Comment: D'oh couldn't see the wood for the trees.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to avoid this. If you don't want to use the package name, simply just put a `.` before importing a package. By doing that you can call a public fn or use a public var of that package. After doing that your `main.go` and `cmd/a.go` files look like below:

**`main.go`**:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        . "github.com/go-test/mod-test/cmd"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("main")
        A()
}
```

**`cmd/a.go`**:

```
package cmd

import (
        "fmt"
        . "github.com/go-test/mod-test/pkg/foo"
)

func A() {
        fmt.Println("a")
        B()
}
```